# How to use wxWidgets types in own classes?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am writing an application based on wxWidgets library. I had some classes which support application data. They use types as std::string, which shouldn't be used in application written with wxWidgets lib.
E.g.

```
class SomeClass
{
    private:
      char name[80];
      (.....)
    public:
      (.....)
};
```

Now I have something like that:

```
class SomeClass
{
    private:
      wxString name;
      (.....)
    public:
      (.....)
};
```

(Yes, I know that char isn't string - I decided to change char to string).
Compiler throws error:
'wxString' does not name a type
I tried to include file with class in many places, but result is always the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If compiler says the wxString is not declared then you must include the proper header.

Declare this line, make sure it's NOT inside of `#ifndef WX_PRECOMP`.

```
#include <wx/string.h>
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! But I've got a question.  Why precompiled version of the header doesn't work right?

Comment: @KacperKołodziej Precompiled headers **do** work I found out today. Just make sure that your declarations are NOT inside of `#ifndef WX_PRECOMP`, this is opposite of what the wxWidgets samples say.